# Fetch data from database with dropdown selected option

Tags: theme-development

[image]

I have a custom database table, `location( id, country, city, latitude, longtitude )`

2 page : `country.php`(display all countries) and country `detail.php` (display cities for each country in the dropdown) that my code in the pic work perfectly

But I want to display latitude and longtitude for city selected option in the field text

```
<select name="state" id="address" class="form-control">
Global $wpdb;
$code = get_query_var('country');
$result = $wpdb->get_results ( "SELECT city, latitude FROM location 
WHERE country = '$code'");

foreach($result as $row) {
$city=$row->city;
?>
 <option value="<?php echo $city; ?>"><?php echo $city; ?</option>
<?php
}
?>
</select>
```

Comment: You would show it the same way you show the city. Can you edit your question so that the code is in a code block rather than a photograph? The syntax highlighting is nice but it's impossible to search the text in the image, and anybody who wants to try and test or reproduce it has to type it out manually

Comment: But how i can do that , I tried a lot without result , Do I have to add other request ?

Comment: You have `$city = $row->city`, have you tried doing that but with `latitude` instead? Your query asks for `city` and `latitude` but you only use `city` for some reason. Did you write this code?

Comment: i edit the code

Comment: @TomJNowell  please can you see now ??